# Why is my VBA Loop giving me a 'Run-Time 13 Error: Mismatch'?

Tags: excel, vba

I previously created a delete function that goes through all of the sheets in my workbook looking for a specific value found in the "C" column. I've updated my workbook by rearranging the worksheets to be easier for the end user to go between sheets.

The function works fine for all of the sheets with values, until it hits the reporting sheets. When the reporting sheets are opened, the "Run-Time Error:13 Mismatch" pops up. This is very weird because when I try to run the same function as my previous workbook I get no "Run-Time Errors", only that the delete has worked.

How do I fix this code to not run the Run Time Error?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim IDRef As String

IDRef = InputBox("Please enter the selected ID.")
If IDRef = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

        With ws.Cells(i, "C")
            If .Value = IDRef Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End With

    Next i
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any errors (N/A, VALUE, etc.) in column C on those sheets? What is the value of `ws.Cells(i, "C")` when the error occurs? Note - a filter will be faster than looping row by row.

Comment: @BigBen Column C does not have any errors in any of the sheets. I am not sure what the value is, but I am positive it is just the last row number the function is looking at. I will look into a filter, however this loop has worked perfectly up until now.

Comment: Well add a watch to the `.Value` of the cell, or figure out what `i` is when the error occurs and check your sheet. We need that detail to help you.

Comment: If it is the last row number the function is looking at, is that row 2: `...ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2`?

Comment: I already test your code and it is working... Could you bring some sample?

Comment: @BigBen I was able to figure out why my code was getting stuck on the reports. Seemed that rearranging my worksheets somehow messed up my equations I forgot I had added.